# Python script is working on local but not on Ubuntu server

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, web-crawler

This is my first post on this forum and I hope to explain my problem the right way.

So I wrote this little web crawler to update me when the price of a product on Amazon is updating the price. After that it is sending me a notification at Telegram.

```py
def check_price():
    page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    title = soup.find(id='priceblock_ourprice').get_text() # this is the problematic line
    converted_price = title[0:6]
    converted_price = float(converted_price.replace(',', '.'))

    if os.path.exists('data.txt'):
        with open('data.txt', 'r+') as f:
            f_contents = f.read()

            if converted_price != float(f_contents):
                send_msg('The price was updated to: ' + str(converted_price) + '€')
                f.write(str(converted_price))
    else:
        send_msg('The price was updated to: ' + str(converted_price) + '€')
        with open('data.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(str(converted_price))
    return
```

The problem is now that it works on my local machine and I get the notification. But when I try to run the code on the server I get this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "main.py", line 44, in <module>
      check_price()
   File "main.py", line 16, in check_price
      title = soup.find(id='priceblock_ourprice').get_text()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

I just post the main function for checking the price and not the sending because the problem is occurring before that.
I can't find the error in the way I did it. I hope you can help me and thanks.

Comment: The error says that the variable `title` is of `type` `None`. That means that the `soup.find` call didn't return any value. The reason for that could be multiple things, however, one thing that it could be is because `soup` itself didn't return a valid web-page. Could you please verify that the Ubuntu Server can reach the site in question?

Comment: The returned html doesn't have  a tag with that id. The first step is to check `page.status_code` to see if there is an error. Next is to print `page.content` to look for hints.

Comment: @tdelaney with your help I found a problem. So I provide a user agent I generate with my browser on the local machine. With that It works but I on the server I get a automated message and not the side I want. Two days ago It worked like that.

Comment: Are you using that same user agent string on the server?

Comment: @tdelaney Yes because I have no GUI and don't know how to get a user agent string on that. Sorry, pretty new and a total noob.

Comment: A canned user agent string is usually the right thing to do. if it works on your local machine it should work on the server also.

Comment: @tdelaney What do you mean with 'canned' in this context? I'm not a native english speeker, sorry.

Comment: Sorry about that. "canned" means "hard coded". That is, you have the user agent hard coded as a string in your program and use the exact same value on both machines. It wasn't clear to me whether you were getting it dynamically on the machines.

Comment: @tdelaney Thank you for the explanation. That's the way I have it in the program. I have it over the function I posted. It's in the variable 'headers' and I pass it in the first line of the function via the `page = request.get(page.content, headers=headers)`.